# What ways are there for webpages to communicate with servers?

Tags: http

All that I know of are HTTP GET and POST requests.

On our school servers, we can play some games but not others. It seems that we cannot play any games where there is real-time information. So I'm thinking that real-time information requires a different method for the game to communicate with the server, and this method is blocked.

What other ways are there for webpages to communicate with servers?

Comment: Sounds like your school blocks the TCP or UDP ports that the game uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GET/PUT requests is the old-school way to communicate with a webserver.  Once a webpage has been loaded, it can use Java/Flash applets, AJAX, or WebSockets to communicate with the webserver over a separate connection without having to leaving the current page.  This allows for bidirectional communication and real-time updating of the webpage content.

Comment: We're trying to play Flash games. Do you know what the connection is called? I want to find out more about it.